# ReferenceError: done is not defined

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

```
const express = require('express');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const port = 8000;
const app = express();
const expressLayout = require('express-ejs-layouts');
const db = require('./config/mongoose')

// used for session cookie
const session = require('express-session')
const passport = require('passport')
const passportLocal = require('./config/passport-local-strategy')

app.use(express.urlencoded())

app.use(cookieParser());

// where to look static files like css,js
app.use(express.static('./assets'))


// this line must be above the routes line (line no. 11 in this case) because in the routes all the views are going to be render and before that we have to tell to the browser the layout
app.use(expressLayout)

// extract style and scripts from sub pages into the layout
app.set('layout extractStyles', true);
app.set('layout extractScripts', true);


// set up the view engine
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', './views');

app.use(session({
    name: 'iFacebook',
    // TODO change the secret before deployment in production mode
    secret: 'Coder',
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false,
    cookie: {
        maxAge : (1000*60*100)
    }
}))

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session())


// use express router
// require('./routes/index) is similar to require('./routes) in this case, it by default fetch routes
app.use('/', require('./routes/index'))

app.listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(`Error in running the server : ${err}`);
    }
    console.log(`Server is listening at ${port}`);
})
```

I am using passport and passport-local strategy and this error comes and even i did not know from which file this error comes. I am sharing the index.js file code which is the server file. This is the first time i am using this even on the documentation i did not found anything

Comment: can you add `./config/passport-local-strategy.js`'s code

Comment: Please include the actual stack trace from the error.  That will tell you which file and line number in that file the error originates in and then you can include the relevant code from that file in your question.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.